# issue in new post submission with ACF on front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Advanced Custom field for a custom post type to allow user to add post from front end. My update code is working fine. Inserting new post is not working fine. Its just adding a post, but no data is saved.

I have tried following code.

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
if( $post_id != 'new_post' ) {
    // Get the selected post status
    $value = get_field('post_status_field', $post_id);

    // Update current post
    $post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_status'   => $value,    
      'post_title'  => $_POST['acf']['_post_title'],

    );

    // Remove the action to avoid infinite loop
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);

    // Update the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_update_post( $post );


    // Add the action back
    do_action('acf/save_post', $post_id, 20);

}else{
    // Get the selected post status
    $value = get_field('post_status_field', $post_id);

    // Update current post
    $post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_status'   => $value,    
      'post_title'  => $_POST['acf']['_post_title'],

    );

    // Remove the action to avoid infinite loop
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);

    // Update the post into the database
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );


    // Add the action back
    do_action('acf/save_post', $post_id, 20);


}
return $post_id;
}

// run after ACF saves the $_POST['acf'] data
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

I am not able to figure out, where I am getting wrong. I want when a post is submitted, all data is submitted and when updated, all data must update.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing, I solved that yesterday.
When you hooking on 'acf/save_post' you running function, while custom field has old value, you sending new values with $_POST, but with get_field() you getting old values :D
So instead

```
$value = get_field('post_status_field', $post_id);
```

You need to use, in both situations, else you need press update button twice

```
$value =  $_POST['acf']['FIELD_KEY'];
```

to get FIELD_KEY do

```
var_dump( $_POST['acf']); die();
```

Comment: Now, it is saving two records. Do I just need to change $value only? or anything else also? Can you update my code? I want to add a new post from front end and update existing post.

Comment: Whole function hooked on post creation/update, don't run second time $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );, do update instead, and post_id you passing trough when calling the function. I hope that helps

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this answer helped me in solving an issue in which I have two fields for an event- "event_start_date" and "event_end_date"; and in cases that an end date is not entered, I created a function using the `acf/save_post` action to copy the start date into the end date field. Using `get_field` with the field label wasn't working—that is, I needed to update the post twice to actually get the value saved—but using `$_POST['acf']['FIELD_KEY']` as detailed above did work.